# Java Eclipse Installation Difficulties

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, oomph

My Eclipse was running slow, so I decided to uninstall and reinstall it. It seems that Eclipse only installs files into my Users directory, so I just deleted them for my uninstall. If there is a cleaner uninstall that would remedy the following installation problem, that would be awesome.

So when reinstalling, I received an error. Here's the installation log:

```
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_161-b12
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.oxygen
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.9.0.v20171202-1121, build=3282, branch=f99b41819cc9f86beec6b54bf453173fc2d4acef
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.9.0.v20171202-1121, build=3282, branch=f99b41819cc9f86beec6b54bf453173fc2d4acef
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.9.0.v20171202-1121, build=3282, branch=f99b41819cc9f86beec6b54bf453173fc2d4acef
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Oxygen))
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Offline = false
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Mirrors = true
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Resolving 25 requirements from 3 repositories to C:\Users\Cobal\eclipse\java-oxygen\eclipse
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement epp.package.java [4.7.0,4.8.0)
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.7.0,4.8.0)
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.7.0,4.8.0)
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.news.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.snipmatch.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen
[2018-03-30 12:56:56] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2018-03-30 12:56:59] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen.
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository code=0 An error occurred while downloading http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen/content.xml.xz. The cache file C:\Users\Cobal\.p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache\downloading\-1747184149 could not be renamed to C:\Users\Cobal\.p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache\-1747184149.
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.updateCache(CacheManager.java:428)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCacheFromFile(CacheManager.java:132)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:56)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:78)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:117)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:409)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:201)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:476)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.addChild(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:166)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.<init>(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:106)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:122)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:117)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:409)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:201)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:476)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$RepositoryLoader$Worker.perform(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:1613)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.WorkerPool$Worker.run(WorkerPool.java:428)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)

[2018-03-30 12:56:59] 
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_161-b12
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.oxygen
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.9.0.v20171202-1121, build=3282, branch=f99b41819cc9f86beec6b54bf453173fc2d4acef
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.9.0.v20171202-1121, build=3282, branch=f99b41819cc9f86beec6b54bf453173fc2d4acef
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.9.0.v20171202-1121, build=3282, branch=f99b41819cc9f86beec6b54bf453173fc2d4acef
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Oxygen))
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Offline = false
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Mirrors = true
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Resolving 25 requirements from 3 repositories to C:\Users\Cobal\eclipse\java-oxygen\eclipse
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement epp.package.java [4.7.0,4.8.0)
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.7.0,4.8.0)
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.7.0,4.8.0)
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.news.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.snipmatch.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen
[2018-03-30 12:57:15] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2018-03-30 12:57:16] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen.
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository code=0 An error occurred while downloading http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen/content.xml.xz. The cache file C:\Users\Cobal\.p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache\downloading\-1747184149 could not be renamed to C:\Users\Cobal\.p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache\-1747184149.
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.updateCache(CacheManager.java:428)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCacheFromFile(CacheManager.java:132)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:56)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:78)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:117)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:409)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:201)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:476)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.addChild(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:166)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.<init>(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:106)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:122)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:117)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:409)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:201)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:476)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$RepositoryLoader$Worker.perform(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:1613)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.WorkerPool$Worker.run(WorkerPool.java:428)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)

[2018-03-30 12:57:16]
```

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the following file and reinstall it : 
C:\Users\Cobal.p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache-1747184149

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just installing it in another folder. I guess there was still some other eclipse file somewhere in my Users directory, so installing in a different place worked fine. Not really a proper fix, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a clean reinstall of eclipse, you can delete the content of the following folders in your user directory `C:\Users\Cobal\`:

- `.eclipse`
- `.p2`
- `.tooling`

Please note that these folders can be used by other eclipse instances. If you have multiple eclipse installations on your pc, delete these folders with care, make a backup.